# Actions performed during Devi Paksha affects the individual tremendously?

Tags: sin, devi, navrathri

Are their any such stories or myth, where people are being blessed or cursed by the Goddess for their deeds, which are performed during this phase of Devi paksha?
I would like to know, if sinful acts performed during this phase, will affect the individual in any major way.

Answer (score 7):

It should be like that. Because if a bad deed is done in an auspicious time (like say in Devi Paksha) or in a holy place (like say in a Tirtha like Kasi) then the result (of that sin) is said to be magnified to a great extent.

Here is a passage from the **Devi Bhagavatam Book 4, Chapter 8** which proves my point for "holy places". For the "holy times" the result should be the same by inference.

> 34. Know, O king! the mind as the principal factor in any religious act or in any holy place. He who wants purity, let him first make his
>       own mind pure.
> 35. **The residents in any holy place deceive others and thus incur great sins. The sins committed in a place of pilgrimage can never be
>       removed; they become unending and inexhaustible.**